# Partially read/parse JSON file data kotlin

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, kotlin

I am using Kotlin and I have the following JSON in `myfile.json`:

```
[
  {
    "username": "bioround",
    "id": 1,
    "data": {
      "nicknames": [
        "bio",
        "round"
      ],
      "address": "address"
    }
  },
  {
    "username": "roundbio",
    "id": 2,
    "data": {
      "nicknames": [
        "round"
      ],
      "address": "address2"
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to only *partially* parse the data from this file. I want to store each json object as a string, but maintain the list structure. So after parsing this I want to end up with a list where each element is a string representation of the json object.

For example, after parsing the element at index 0 in my list will be the string representation of the json object at index 0 of the json list.

How can I do this?

Comment: Would you mind sharing why you'd want to do that?

Comment: This is for a custom use case where the JSON files are pre-existing. I would like to read the json objects as strings, which I can then execute grep-like regex searches on. When I find a match, I want to correlate it with the index of the object in which it was found. Reading the objects as strings while maintaining the original list structure was the solution to this problem that I thought of. However, if you can think of a better solution I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to implement your own Json parser

Comment: This does not really answers the question.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how I can go about implementing my own parser for this problem?